# How to update one UISwitch when using another UISwitch

Tags: ios, swift

Case: I have 2 UISwitches - Switch1 and Switch2. 
Switch1 controls the visbility of a UILabel in my scene.
Switch2 once activated turns Switch1 off as well as its visbility.

Problem: After Switch2 is activated Switch1 turns off as well as disappears however my UILabel is still visible in my scene.

```
switch1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switch1Action), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)
switch2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switch2Action), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)


    @objc func switch1Action(switch1: UISwitch) {
        if switch1.isOn {

            lockedMessage.isHidden = false
            }
        if !switch1.isOn {

            lockedMessage.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    @objc func switch2Action(switch2: UISwitch) {

        if switch2.isOn {

            switch1.isOn = false
            switch1.isHidden = true

        }
```

Many thanks! :)

Comment: Yeah thats one way of doing it, thanks. Although now Im repeating my code inside multiple functions.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct and desired behavior. Since you explicitly changed the value, it is up to you to decide how to handle the changed value.

The reason for this is because it is not uncommon to explicitly change the value of control after being notified of its value being changed through user interaction. If the explicit state change caused the event to fire again, you would end up in an infinite loop. "@rmaddy"

---

Deprecated (since the original question updated):

You (probably accidentally) set a unrelated condition for hiding the `label`. (What is `moveWall` ?).

Try this instead:

```
@objc func switch1Action(switch1: UISwitch) {
    lockedMessage.isHidden = !switch1.isOn
    ,,,
}
```

Comment: My question is that if Switch2 turns off Switch1 why doesnt swift see that the state of the switch1 has changed therefore running the code inside switch1Action? Otherwise now Im just repeating code inside my switchActions.

Comment: This is correct and desired behavior. Check the answer.

Comment: Okay thank you, everybody is on the mark, appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your issue correctly, then it seems you want lockedMessage to be hidden if switch2 is on as well. If this is the case – you can change the visibility of the lockedMessage within your function switch2Action.

```
@objc func switch2Action(switch2: UISwitch) {

    if switch2.isOn {
        switch1.isOn = false
        switch1.isHidden = true
        lockedMessage.isHidden = true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `switch1.isOn` programmatically will not trigger the `switch1Action`. You need to hide the message label from `switch2Action`.

For reference see the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswitch/1623686-seton):

> Setting the switch to either position does not result in an action message being sent.